# Why would a program work well if activated manually but not as a daemon using crontab, mysql and python?

Tags: python, mysql, cron, pymysql

We have this code, of which the purpose is simply to publish in the database in MySQLWorkbench:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import os, time
import datetime

#Conexion a la base de datos
conn = pymysql.connect(‘example.example.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com', user= ‘xxxx', port= xxxx,     passwd = ‘xxxxx', db=‘xxxx')

def query():
    fecha = (str) (datetime.datetime.now())
    nfecha = fecha.split(' ')
    dia = nfecha[0]
    hora = nfecha[1]
    tabla='notificaciones'
    idcliente='1'
    notificacion='hola'
    tipo='saludo'
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('insert into notificaciones(idcliente, notificacion, tipo, fecha, hora)     values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (idcliente, notificacion, tipo, dia, hora))
        conn.commit()

    print('success')


def main():
    query()

main()
```

When executed manually in the console, the code works great, however, when we want to set it as daemon, using crontab, it doesn't do anything.

In crontab tried this way:

```
sudo su
crontab -e
@reboot sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/DataBase.py
```

I've tried calling it from another program and already as an individual program. It doesn't work at all.

Help.

Comment: Look at the output of stderr.

Comment: Don't split the current timestamp into date and time, instead, use a TIMESTAMP-field in your database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this case was: the program needed internet connection, then it needed some time before starting to give enough time so the OS comes up and the internet connection is established. It was solved adding a timer or sleep to the program in order to have the internet connection first.

Answer (score 0):

sudo does not run inside crontab command. It generally requires an explicit tty or visudo exception configured.

If you really require sudo priviledges, configure this crontab (without sudo) under root user, which you already seem to be doing. That'll be all.

i.e.

```
sudo su
crontab -e
@reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/DataBase.py
```